# Not able to Connect to Snowflake through externalbrowser authenticator from Docker container

Tags: docker, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When i am trying to connect to Snowflake through python script inside an docker container getting below error.

snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError: Failed to connect to DB: cisco.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443,
Unable to open a browser in this environment.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to make the connection

Comment: Does the Docker container have a browser?

Comment: I found a solution for that in this other thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/75750504/5706548

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the docker container can not open a browser which is required for browser-based SSO via externalbrowser option.

If you are using OKTA as IDP, Then You can use native SSO from the docker container. See the below document for more details.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#native-sso-okta-only